# Active record update_attribute executes a DELETE query on an associated object(child) of an object(parent) when parent is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Rails: 3.0.11**

**Ruby: 1.9.3**

*Why does active record update_attribute executes a DELETE query on an associated object(child) of an object(parent) when I updated the parent?*

Following are my classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_keywords, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :keywords, :through => :user_keywords

end

class UserKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :keyword
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_keywords
  has_many :users, :through => :user_keywords
end
```

On front-end I have a checkbox for each keyword.

- Checkbox: Keyword 1
- Checkbox: Keyword 2
- Checkbox: Keyword 3
- Checkbox: Keyword 4

First time I checked "Keyword 1" and "Keyword 2" checkboxes to update the user's keywords.

I again edited the user to update the associated keywords by checking "Keyword 1" and "Keyword 3" checkboxes and updated the user.
The second updated deleted the previous records in my USER_KEYWORDS table.

Following is my console output showing the DELETE statement being executed:

```
  User Load (55.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  Keyword Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" WHERE "keywords"."id" IN (1, 3)
  Keyword Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "keywords".* FROM "keywords" INNER JOIN "user_keywords" ON "keywords".id = "user_keywords".keyword_id WHERE (("user_keywords".user_id = 5))
  AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "user_keywords" WHERE "user_keywords"."user_id" = 5 AND "user_keywords"."keyword_id" = 2
  AREL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "user_keywords" ("keyword_id", "user_id", "status", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (3, 5, 'f', '2012-06-12 13:15:43.912236', '2012-06-12 13:15:43.912236')
```

The :dependent option on has_many method says (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference):

### 4.3.2.6 :dependent

If you set the :dependent option to :destroy, then deleting this object will call the destroy method on the associated objects to delete those objects. If you set the :dependent option to :delete_all, then deleting this object will delete the associated objects without calling their destroy method. If you set the :dependent option to :nullify, then deleting this object will set the foreign key in the associated objects to NULL.

This option is ignored when you use the :through option on the association. ##

I am unable to understand this behavior.Can anybody please elaborate or clarify in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete statement only deleted the the association for keyword 2.  When you submitted the form with two checkboxes checked, the system assumes that you want those two items associated, but none of the others that were not checked.  Therefore, when it loaded the current `user_keyword` associations, it saw that there was one existing record that you did not choose to keep, so it deleted it.  It then saw that there was one new one, so it created a new one.

If you want to only add relationships, and not remove relationships, then I would not recommend checkboxes, as checking a checkbox implies adding, but removing a check implies destroying the relationship (which is what rails did in this case).  A button with AJAX functionality might make more sense.  If you do want to keep checkboxes, but not allow rails to destroy relationships that weren't selected, then you would have to build the relationships yourself based on the parameters, and not rely on the rails magic to do the job for you.

Note that this is not related to the `:dependent` option, this is simply due to the relationship you have set up in the models and in the form.

Comment: Thanks Justin for elaboration.Can you please point me to the documentation/resources which states about mentioned behavior of checkboxes?

Comment: Take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association specifically: `The collection of join models can be managed via the API. For example, if you assign

physician.patients = patients
new join models are created for newly associated objects, and if some are gone their rows are deleted.

Automatic deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered.` With the checkboxes you are essentially passing a list of keywords to users via update_attributes.  Any missing keywords are automatically removed.

Comment: Best practice would be to ensure the checkboxes are pre-populated when you enter the form according to whether or not that relationship already exists.  That way, you would have to explicitly remove a checkbox in order to delete that relationship.

Comment: And what happens if `User` validation fails? It will update `user_keywords` in the database but won't save the user record, thus leading to inconsistent state. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @MilovanZogovic From [autosave_association.rb](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html) : _Saving of the parent, its associations, and the destruction of marked associations, all happen inside a transaction. This should never leave the database in an inconsistent state._ Turns out the documentation here is what I should have provided to explain the checkboxes behavior.

Comment: @Jignesh You can find a more comprehensive introduction on [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?view=asciicast).